# Is it possible to create master-detail relationship in Oracle Forms when both of the blocks are based on procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I have two blocks that are based on procedure and I want to create master-detail relationship between them.

I do this using Data Block Wizzard. It create trigger `ON-CHECK-DELETE-MASTER`, this trigger assumes that my detail block is based on table `(FRL_XXX.TRIGGERS_QUERY, but it is a procedure)` and generates cursor:

```
CURSOR TRIGGERS_cur IS      
SELECT 1 FROM FRL_XXX.TRIGGERS_QUERY F     
WHERE F.PTG_PST_CODE = :S_TYPES.PST_CODE;
```

Is there any workaround to solve this problem?

When I try delete this trigger or remove the cursor I get error:

`FRM-30409: Delete Record Behavior for the relation is invalid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never done that, but - let me think aloud.

If data block is based on a procedure, it means that procedure returns (as its IN OUT parameter) an array. I'd say that you'll have to

- create your own trigger (i.e. replace the one created by the Wizard

  - note that these triggers usually have a comment "don't modify it!". If you run the Wizard again, it might overwrite your code, so *safer* approach is to create a procedure which will do the job, and call that procedure from the trigger
- declare a local variable (array) and fetch data into it; pass all parameters to the procedure as you did while calling it in order to populate data block
- review array's contents and check whether there's any row that satisfies condition `PTG_PST_CODE = :S_TYPES.PST_CODE`
- if so, do what Wizard's trigger does in that case

Basically, I think that you'll have to write your own process which will replace default Forms behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In Procedure based blocks, If you choose the Relation type as `Isolated` , Oracle form will allow the Master Detail relationship between two blocks because in that case `ON-CHECK-DELETE-MASTER` trigger won't be there.

You will be able to retrieve the records from detail block as `ON-POPULATE-DETAILS` trigger will work as-usual.

In my case, only detail block was based on Procedure and it's working fine.

Note : `Isolated` type of relationship will delete the master records even if child records exist. You need to handle this case separately.

Please share your approach step by step, if you went ahead as per [littlefoot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9097906/littlefoot)